# Basic Structures int get function or reading from text file

Tags: c

I have to create function int get(struct telephone list[ ]); ,which will load name and number from  text file .The text file can be more than 5 items long but I have to load just 5 of them .  But when I put instead char *fname the structure ,it does not work . Shouldn't be inside the int get function what file I want to read or the input ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_ARRAY_SIZE 5

struct telephone
{
    char name[30];
    int number;

};

struct telephone list[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE];

int load(char *fname);

int main()
{
    char *fname = "BP";

    load(fname);

    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {

        printf("Name and phone is : %s\n %d\n", list[i].name,list[i].number);
        printf("%d\n",count);
        count++;
    }

    return 0;
}

int load(char *fname)
{
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    int  i = 0;

    if ((fp = fopen(fname, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error : Unable to open for reading\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fscanf(fp, "%s %d", &list[i].name, &list[i].number) != EOF)
    {
        i++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Hi, please edit your quastion it is not clear what *is* your quastion...

Comment: try writing a simpler project first. instead of a file, make an array with test data. Test your code to process that data using the array. When that is working add the file access.

Comment: `if ((fp = fopen(fname, "r")) == NULL) { perror(fname); return -1; }`  Error messages should be informative and written to the proper stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the actual question you're asking:

> Shouldn't be inside of int get function what file I want to read or the input ?

It's a bit hard to follow your English, but I think you're asking about how the `get()` function you are supposed to write would determine from which file to read the data.

It's unclear precisely what your instructor expects, but inasmuch as the function's parameters do not include a file name, there are two main alternatives:

1. Use a pre-determined file name.  There are numerous variations on this, but the absolute simplest is to pass a string literal to `fopen()`, something like this:

   ```
   FILE *telephone = fopen("telephone.txt");
   ```
2. Use a file-scope variable (sometimes misleadingly called a "global" variable) pointing to the file name to convey the data.  Set the variable appropriately before calling the `get()` function, using data prompted from the user, from a program argument, or from some other source.